# Creating a date calculator in C

Tags: c

I need to create a basic date calculator in C that will have the user input a date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.  I have the basics of it down.  Although I don't need to, I want to go the extra little bit and factor in for leap years.  The program runs fine; however, it doesn't calculate leap years correctly.  When I enter a date of `2016-02-26`, I should have an expected result of `2016-03-04` but I get the result of `2016-03-03`.  I'd reckon that if I used an if else statement to the effect of the following using modulo.

```
if (month == 2 && year % 4) days = 29; 
   else days = 28;
```

Here's my full code...

```
//Does not require <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Set variables
int newDay, newMonth, newYear, daysInMonth, daysRemain;
// Set structure for day month year
struct date {
    int day, month, year;
};
// set structure for date
struct date d1;

int main (void) {
    //Intro
    printf("Date calculation program by Keith A. Russell");
    //Asks for user input
    printf("\n\nPlease enter the year in four digit format (YYYY) ");
    scanf("%i", &d1.year);
    printf("\nEnter the month in two digit format (MM) ");
    scanf("%i", &d1.month);
    printf("\nEnter the day in two digit format (DD) ");
    scanf("%i", &d1.day);
    //Runs calculations to increase the date by a week
    newDay = d1.day + 7;
    newMonth = d1.month;
    newYear = d1.year;
    daysRemain = 0;
    //For if the next week is going to be greater than the next month
    if (newDay > 28)
        checkMonth();  //Runs checkMonth Function
    //Prints the dates
    printf("\nThe new date is %i-%i-%i: \n", newYear, newMonth, newDay);
}

checkMonth() {
    if (d1.month == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12)
        daysInMonth = 31;               //For months with 31 days
    if (d1.month == 2 && d1.year % 4)   //Attempt to calculate leap year
        daysInMonth = 29;
    else {
        daysInMonth = 28;           //All other years
    }
    if (d1.month == 4 || 6 || 9 || 11)  //For months with 30 days
        daysInMonth = 30;
    //Sets up to advance the year if approaching the end of year
    if (newDay > daysInMonth) {
        daysRemain = newDay - daysInMonth;
        newDay = daysRemain;
        newMonth++;
        checkYear();
    }
}
//Runs function to advance to the next year
checkYear() {
    if (d1.month == 12)
        if (daysRemain > 0) {
            newYear++;
            newMonth = 1;
        }
}
```

If there are more elegant ways of calculating the leap year and including it in this program, I'd appreciate that greatly.  Thank you.

Comment: Note that your leap year calculation is sloppy.  It's OK for years in the range 1901..2099; it fails on 1900 and 2100 (neither of which is/was a leap year).  If year is divisible by 400, it's a leap year; otherwise, if year is divisible by 100, it's not a leap year; otherwise, if year is divisible by 4, it's a leap year; otherwise, it's not.  That's not the best sequence for calculating the result; it is for giving the rules, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: the leap year calculation is actually completely broken: it only yields correct results for 1700, 1800, 1900, 2100...

Comment: @chqrlie: Urg!  Looks like you're right — I didn't notice the implicit inversion of the condition.  Well, I'm reduced to using as an excuse "I recognized that there's a problem" and "I think I diagnosed the correct algorithm".  Calendrical calculations are remarkably fraught due to the rococo (if not baroque) nature of the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: calendrical calculations are indeed an intricate problem, especially if you want to take into account the lesser known but major modification in the date for the year change and the non uniform adoption by different countries and churches. Here is a savvy reference: http://www.powells.com/book/calendrical-calculations-9780521702386/61-1

Comment: @chqrlie: "Calendrical Calculations" is an interesting book; I have both the 3rd edition you link to and the prior 'Millennium Edition'.  The code is written in a dialect of LISP, which adds to the fun.

Answer (score 2):

well for a start this is wrong

```
if (d1.month == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12)
```

It will always be true. You need

```
if (d1.month == 1 || d1.month == 3 || d1.month == 5 ....)
```

Comment: Interesting, I thought this introduced a new bug (err... unexpected feature) as it was giving a different result than I had anticipated.  But I did figure out that the program does not include the day entered.  So it gives an answer of a week and a day.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
if (d1.month == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12)
```

You can't compare one value to a list of values like this.  What you're actually doing is this:

```
if ((d1.month == 1) || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12)
```

You're comparing `d1.month` against the value 1, but then you take that boolean result and do a logical OR with several other numbers.  Since all of these numbers is non-zero, this expression will always evaluate to true.

The same goes for this:

```
if (d1.month == 4 || 6 || 9 || 11)
```

You need to explicitly compare against each value:

```
if ((d1.month == 1) || (d1.month == 3) || (d1.month == 5) ...
```

You could actually do this more cleanly with a `switch` with fallthrough cases:

```
switch (d1.month) {
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 8:
case 10:
case 12:
    daysInMonth = 31;
    break;
case 4:
case 6:
case 9:
case 11:
    daysInMonth = 30;
    break;
case 2:
    // years divisible by 100 are not leap years, unless they are also divisible by 400
    daysInMonth = (d1.year % 400 == 0) ? 29 :
                  (d1.year % 100 == 0) ? 28 :
                  (d1.year % 4 == 0) ? 29 : 28;
    break;
}
```

Comment: always evaluate to true, not false

Comment: @pm100  Good catch.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- The test for leap years is incorrect: `(d1.month == 2 && d1.year % 4)` indicates a normal year between 1901 and 2099 which is non-leap. The correct test is this:

  ```
  if (d1.month == 2 && (d1.year % 4) == 0)   //Attempt to calculate leap year
      daysInMonth = 29;
  ```

  Note however that according to the Gregorian reformed calendar, years multiples of 100 that are not also multiples of 400 are not leap years, so the complete test is this:

  ```
  if (d1.month == 2) {
      daysInMonth = (d1.year % 4 || (!(d1.year % 100) && (d1.year % 400)) ? 28 : 29;
  }
  ```
- Your tests for month values are incorrect: instead of `if (d1.month == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12)`, you should write:

  ```
  if (d1.month == 1 || d1.month == 3 || d1.month == 5 || d1.month == 7 ||
      d1.month == 8 || d1.month == 10 || d1.month == 12)
  ```

To make the code more readable, you could use a `switch` statement. If you first check that `d1.month` is between 1 and 12, you can condense the above test into a more compact single test:

```
if ((1 << d1.month) & ((1 << 1) | (1 << 3) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 7) | (1 << 8) | (1 << 10) | (1 << 12))) {
    daysInMonth = 31;
}
```

Comment: It might be a little quicker to use `if (d1.month == 4 || d1.month == 6 || d1.month == 9 || d1.month == 11)` and use 30 days when it is true, 31 otherwise; it is fewer conditions to test before coming up with a definitive answer.